Noisy double exponential curve fitting
We have a measured data set with a relationship with the following formula:
$$Y = A\cdot \exp(B\cdot T) + C\cdot \exp(D\cdot T)$$
How can we approximate the values ​​of A, B, C and D? The method used should be fast and implementable with slow processors. The main purpose is programming in C language.
I approximated with the help of MATLAB software. The result was excellent, but I don't understand the working algorithm of MATLAB software.
clc
clear
%%
A = [
   43,   116,   389,   554,   674,   803,   861,   731,  1021,  1011,  1176,  1243,  1306,  1393,  1479, ...
 1459,  1635,  1694,  1745,  1795,  1803,  1850,  1780,  1869,  1806,  2003,  2140,  2001,  2056,  2154, ...
 2211,  2298,  2245,  2256,  2373,  2365,  2333,  2457,  2368,  2417,  2355,  2393,  2492,  2460,  2575, ...
 2492,  2492,  2570,  2533,  2637,  2601,  2576,  2596,  2677,  2536,  2640,  2632,  2660,  2767,  2784, ...
 2829,  2795,  2781,  2825,  2694,  2905,  2782,  2725,  2864,  2780,  2587,  2849,  2909,  2918,  2913, ...
 2878,  2885,  2837,  2909,  2836,  2899,  2972,  2835,  2897,  2999,  2851,  3019,  2970,  2941,  2932, ...
 2969,  3011,  2941,  2853,  2840,  2881,  3012,  2929,  2909,  3022,  2975,  2974,  2977,  2970,  3107, ...
 3043,  2996,  2985,  2859,  2940,  2982,  2941,  3051,  3066,  3049,  3107,  2997,  2976,  3089,  3023, ...
 3088,  3027,  3008,  2973,  2926,  2999,  2975,  3112,  3112,  3102,  3117,  2970,  3002,  3162,  3020, ...
 3075,  3020,  2989,  3043,  3017,  3066,  3216,  3089,  3250,  3205,  3080,  3137,  3151,  3078,  3095, ...
 3110,  3044,  3112,  3099,  3151,  3202,  3157,  3048,  3145,  3200,  3117,  3157,  3110,  3076,  3080, ...
 3011,  3233,  3194,  3165,  3214,  3225,  3053,  3169,  3090,  3204,  3189,  3119,  3165,  3084,  3017, ...
 3169,  3264,  3245,  3258,  3193,  3227,  3181,  3217,  3126,  3265,  3186,  3165,  3232,  3193,  3026, ...
 3306,  3325,  3240,  3289,  3240, ];

T = [
11316, 11658, 11986, 12328, 12670, 12998, 13340, 13668, 14010, 14338, 14680, 15022, 15350, 15692, 16020, ...
16362, 16690, 17032, 17374, 17702, 18044, 18372, 18714, 19042, 19384, 19726, 20054, 20396, 20724, 21066, ...
21394, 21736, 22078, 22406, 22748, 23076, 23418, 23746, 24088, 24430, 24758, 25100, 25428, 25770, 26098, ...
26440, 26782, 27110, 27452, 27780, 28122, 28450, 28792, 29134, 29462, 29804, 30132, 30474, 30802, 31144, ...
31486, 31814, 32156, 32484, 32826, 33154, 33496, 33838, 34166, 34508, 34836, 35178, 35506, 35848, 36190, ...
36518, 36860, 37188, 37530, 37858, 38200, 38542, 38870, 39212, 39540, 39882, 40210, 40552, 40894, 41222, ...
41564, 41892, 42234, 42562, 42904, 43246, 43574, 43916, 44244, 44586, 44914, 45256, 45598, 45926, 46268, ...
46596, 46938, 47266, 47608, 47950, 48278, 48620, 48948, 49290, 49618, 49960, 50302, 50630, 50972, 51300, ...
51642, 51970, 52312, 52654, 52982, 53324, 53652, 53994, 54322, 54664, 55006, 55334, 55676, 56004, 56346, ...
56674, 57016, 57358, 57686, 58028, 58356, 58698, 59026, 59368, 59710, 60038, 60380, 60708, 61050, 61378, ...
61720, 62062, 62390, 62732, 63060, 63402, 63730, 64072, 64414, 64742, 65084, 65412, 65744, 66086, 66414, ...
66756, 67084, 67426, 67754, 68096, 68438, 68766, 69108, 69436, 69778, 70106, 70448, 70790, 71118, 71460, ...
71788, 72130, 72458, 72800, 73142, 73470, 73812, 74140, 74482, 74810, 75152, 75494, 75822, 76164, 76492, ...
76834, 77162, 77504, 77846, 78174, ];
%%
BBZ = 3165;
T = T'/1000;
YN = BBZ-A';
%%
plot(T, YN)
[population2,gof] = fit(T, YN, 'exp2');
plot(population2,T,YN);

Matlab Fit
Another used method is described in the clip below. It works well for noise-free data, but gives wrong results with the smallest noise.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BL7k2s3tsqU
A solution to this question is given in link "Exponential regression with two terms and constraints". I put its implementation below and compared the result with the MATLAB method.
clc
clear
cla
%%

A = [
   43,   116,   389,   554,   674,   803,   861,   731,  1021,  1011,  1176,  1243,  1306,  1393,  1479, ...
 1459,  1635,  1694,  1745,  1795,  1803,  1850,  1780,  1869,  1806,  2003,  2140,  2001,  2056,  2154, ...
 2211,  2298,  2245,  2256,  2373,  2365,  2333,  2457,  2368,  2417,  2355,  2393,  2492,  2460,  2575, ...
 2492,  2492,  2570,  2533,  2637,  2601,  2576,  2596,  2677,  2536,  2640,  2632,  2660,  2767,  2784, ...
 2829,  2795,  2781,  2825,  2694,  2905,  2782,  2725,  2864,  2780,  2587,  2849,  2909,  2918,  2913, ...
 2878,  2885,  2837,  2909,  2836,  2899,  2972,  2835,  2897,  2999,  2851,  3019,  2970,  2941,  2932, ...
 2969,  3011,  2941,  2853,  2840,  2881,  3012,  2929,  2909,  3022,  2975,  2974,  2977,  2970,  3107, ...
 3043,  2996,  2985,  2859,  2940,  2982,  2941,  3051,  3066,  3049,  3107,  2997,  2976,  3089,  3023, ...
 3088,  3027,  3008,  2973,  2926,  2999,  2975,  3112,  3112,  3102,  3117,  2970,  3002,  3162,  3020, ...
 3075,  3020,  2989,  3043,  3017,  3066,  3216,  3089,  3250,  3205,  3080,  3137,  3151,  3078,  3095, ...
 3110,  3044,  3112,  3099,  3151,  3202,  3157,  3048,  3145,  3200,  3117,  3157,  3110,  3076,  3080, ...
 3011,  3233,  3194,  3165,  3214,  3225,  3053,  3169,  3090,  3204,  3189,  3119,  3165,  3084,  3017, ...
 3169,  3264,  3245,  3258,  3193,  3227,  3181,  3217,  3126,  3265,  3186,  3165,  3232,  3193,  3026, ...
 3306,  3325,  3240,  3289,  3240, ];

T = [
11316, 11658, 11986, 12328, 12670, 12998, 13340, 13668, 14010, 14338, 14680, 15022, 15350, 15692, 16020, ...
16362, 16690, 17032, 17374, 17702, 18044, 18372, 18714, 19042, 19384, 19726, 20054, 20396, 20724, 21066, ...
21394, 21736, 22078, 22406, 22748, 23076, 23418, 23746, 24088, 24430, 24758, 25100, 25428, 25770, 26098, ...
26440, 26782, 27110, 27452, 27780, 28122, 28450, 28792, 29134, 29462, 29804, 30132, 30474, 30802, 31144, ...
31486, 31814, 32156, 32484, 32826, 33154, 33496, 33838, 34166, 34508, 34836, 35178, 35506, 35848, 36190, ...
36518, 36860, 37188, 37530, 37858, 38200, 38542, 38870, 39212, 39540, 39882, 40210, 40552, 40894, 41222, ...
41564, 41892, 42234, 42562, 42904, 43246, 43574, 43916, 44244, 44586, 44914, 45256, 45598, 45926, 46268, ...
46596, 46938, 47266, 47608, 47950, 48278, 48620, 48948, 49290, 49618, 49960, 50302, 50630, 50972, 51300, ...
51642, 51970, 52312, 52654, 52982, 53324, 53652, 53994, 54322, 54664, 55006, 55334, 55676, 56004, 56346, ...
56674, 57016, 57358, 57686, 58028, 58356, 58698, 59026, 59368, 59710, 60038, 60380, 60708, 61050, 61378, ...
61720, 62062, 62390, 62732, 63060, 63402, 63730, 64072, 64414, 64742, 65084, 65412, 65744, 66086, 66414, ...
66756, 67084, 67426, 67754, 68096, 68438, 68766, 69108, 69436, 69778, 70106, 70448, 70790, 71118, 71460, ...
71788, 72130, 72458, 72800, 73142, 73470, 73812, 74140, 74482, 74810, 75152, 75494, 75822, 76164, 76492, ...
76834, 77162, 77504, 77846, 78174, ];
%%
%plot(T, YN)
%[population2,gof] = fit(T, YN, 'exp2');
%plot(population2,T,YN);
%%
x = T'/1000;
BBZ = 3165;
y = BBZ-A';


%figure(1)
hold off
%plot(x, y, 'o')
hold on
%%
SumXn     = 0;
SumYn     = 0;
SumX2n    = 0;
SumX3n    = 0;
SumX4n    = 0;
SumXnYn   = 0;
SumSn     = 0;
SumS2n    = 0;
SumSSn    = 0;
SumSnXn   = 0;
SumSnYn   = 0;
SumSS2n   = 0;
SumX2nYn  = 0;
SumSSnSn  = 0;
SumSSnYn  = 0;
SumSnX2n  = 0;
SumSSnXn  = 0;
SumSSnX2n = 0;
Sn        = 0;
SnLast    = 0;
SSn       = 0;
Items     = 0;
for I=1:length(x)
    Yn = y(I);
    Xn = x(I);
    X2n = Xn*Xn;
    X3n = Xn*X2n;
    X4n = Xn*X3n;
    if(I == 1)
        Sn      = 0;
        SnLast  = 0;
        SSn     = 0;
    else
        SnLast = Sn;
        Sn  = Sn  + 0.5*(y(I)+y(I-1))*(x(I)-x(I-1));
        SSn = SSn + 0.5*(Sn + SnLast)*(x(I)-x(I-1));
    end
    S2n  = Sn  * Sn;
    SS2n = SSn * SSn;

    SumSS2n   = SumSS2n   + SS2n;
    SumSSnSn  = SumSSnSn  + SSn * Sn;
    SumSSnX2n = SumSSnX2n + SSn * X2n;
    SumSSnXn  = SumSSnXn  + SSn * Xn;
    SumSSn    = SumSSn    + SSn;

    SumS2n    = SumS2n    + S2n;
    SumSnX2n  = SumSnX2n  + Sn * X2n;
    SumSnXn   = SumSnXn   + Sn * Xn;
    SumSn     = SumSn     + Sn;

    SumX4n    = SumX4n    + X4n;
    SumX3n    = SumX3n    + X3n;
    SumX2n    = SumX2n    + X2n;

    SumXn     = SumXn     + Xn;
    
    Items     = Items     + 1;

    SumSSnYn  = SumSSnYn  + SSn * Yn;
    SumSnYn   = SumSnYn   + Sn  * Yn;
    SumX2nYn  = SumX2nYn  + X2n * Yn;
    SumXnYn   = SumXnYn   + Xn  * Yn;
    SumYn     = SumYn     + Yn;
end

AA = ([ ...
    SumSS2n   SumSSnSn   SumSSnX2n   SumSSnXn   SumSSn; ...
    SumSSnSn  SumS2n     SumSnX2n    SumSnXn    SumSn ; ...
    SumSSnX2n SumSnX2n   SumX4n      SumX3n     SumX2n; ...
    SumSSnXn  SumSnXn    SumX3n      SumX2n     SumXn ; ...
    SumSSn    SumSn      SumX2n      SumXn      Items ; ...
]);
BB = [ ...
    SumSSnYn; ...
    SumSnYn ; ...
    SumX2nYn; ...
    SumXnYn ; ...
    SumYn   ; ...
];

RES = AA \ BB;

A = RES(1);
B = RES(2);

p = (B + sqrt(B^2 + 4*A)) / 2;
q = (B - sqrt(B^2 + 4*A)) / 2;

SumExPXn = 0;
SumExQXn = 0;
SumEx2PXn = 0;
SumEx2QXn = 0;
SumExPaQXn = 0;
SumYnExpPXn = 0;
SumYnExpQXn = 0;

for I=1:length(x)
    Xn = x(I);
    Yn = y(I);
    SumExPXn = SumExPXn + exp(p*Xn);
    SumExQXn = SumExQXn + exp(q*Xn);
    SumEx2PXn = SumEx2PXn + exp(2*p*Xn);
    SumEx2QXn = SumEx2QXn + exp(2*q*Xn);
    SumExPaQXn = SumExPaQXn + exp((p+q)*Xn);

    SumYnExpPXn = SumYnExpPXn + exp(p*Xn) * Yn;
    SumYnExpQXn = SumYnExpQXn + exp(q*Xn) * Yn;
end

AA = ([ ...
    Items    SumExPXn   SumExQXn  ; ...
    SumExPXn SumEx2PXn  SumExPaQXn; ...
    SumExQXn SumExPaQXn SumEx2QXn ; ...
]);
BB = [ ...
    SumYn      ; ...
    SumYnExpPXn; ...
    SumYnExpQXn; ...
];

RES = AA \ BB;

sA = RES(1);
sB = RES(2);
sC = RES(3);

YY = sA + sB*exp(p*x) + sC*exp(q*x);
%%
plot(x, YY, '-b');
disp('END');

ft = fittype('A*exp(B*x) + C*exp(D*x) + E');
[pop2,gof,output] = fit(x, y, ft, 'StartPoint', [1e3, -0.010, 1e4, -0.100, -500]);

plot(pop2, x, y);


Result:The output result of the code using the MATLAB method

$D$ does not appear in your function?

I need the value of all 4 constants in the relation. (A, B, C, D)

@Rose Your algorithm doesn't find the optimal fit ($sse=8.837e5$).
MATLAB's "Trust-region" algorithm fits better ($sse=8.824e5$).
You also should avoid for-loops in MATLAB.

@gpmath Yes, You are right. I am still looking for more optimal algorithms. Algorithms that can be implemented in other programming languages. I do not understand the algorithm of MATLAB method.

The measured data set has a negative bias, hence we should extend the model formula with bias parameter $E$ to
$$Y = A\cdot e^{B\cdot T}+C\cdot e^{D\cdot T}+E$$
Modification of MATLAB script:
ft = fittype('A*exp(B*x) + C*exp(D*x) + E');
[pop2,gof,output] = fit(T, YN, ft, 'StartPoint', [1e3, -0.010, 1e4, -0.100, -500]);

Result pop2:
 General model:
 pop2(x) = A*exp(B*x) + C*exp(D*x) + E
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   A =        1203  (533.8, 1871)
   B =    -0.01259  (-0.03699, 0.01181)
   C =   1.337e+04  (1.157e+04, 1.516e+04)
   D =     -0.1481  (-0.167, -0.1292)
   E =      -503.2  (-1629, 622.8)

Result gof (goodness of fit):
       sse: 8.824355863574741e+05 (sum-of-squares error)
   rsquare: 0.989753269533616
       dfe: 195
adjrsquare: 0.989543080190715
      rmse: 67.270429605206914

The original approach without parameter E has a poorer goodness of fit:
       sse: 9.857743494119085e+05
   rsquare: 0.988553312881687
       dfe: 196
adjrsquare: 0.988378108487019
      rmse: 70.918692644374715



Your answer is excellent. thank you Now, the problem is that I have to write this code in C language. And I need the algorithm of this method. You can help with this too.

@Rose Do you really need C or better C++ or even better C# ?
And which library do you want to use for the Levenberg-Marquardt fitting?

@Rose I have a C++ implementation of your curve fitting problem using the ALGLIB library.

I'm curious to see how to implement it with C++ or even C#. Can you share the result here?

@Rose It's a MS Visual Studio 2022 Project: MyCppTest1

In order to compare with your results :
The not iterative method and without initial guess is shown below.
From
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integralesand as used in Exponential regression with two terms and constraints
Calculus with MathCad software :

Details of the calculus :

Of course the results depends slightly on the criteria of fitting.
If you prefer a better fit at low values of y instead than at high values it is better to use a criteria of fitting of LMSRE kind than LMSE kind :

If even more accuracy is wanted depending of a particular criteria of fitting one have to use a nonlinear regression software (Thus iterative starting from guessed values of parameters). Then the values computed above are very good initial values.

I agree with you that your approach delivers good initial values for a Trust-region or Levenberg-Marquardt minimizer.
